# cUrl with mutual authentication

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I am trying to do a cUrl to a 3rd party server. They provided me with a p12 file which I installed in my browser. When using the browser I get a response from the server. When doing a cUrl from the linux terminal I get handshake errors.

I extracted the .p12 to a key and cert and then I run the following command:

`curl --key client.key --cert client.crt -X GET -v https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/folder/endpoint`

And get the following reply:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port xxxx (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Do I need to add a self-signed certificate somewhere? I feel like I am missing something. As said earlier, it works from  my browser where the cert was imported so I am certain that there is not an issue with their cert. I know I am missing something.

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you need to add `--cacert` option to the curl command if you have it downloaded or a self-signed certificate (in my case)

`curl --key client.key --cert client.crt --cacert bundle.pem -X GET -v https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/folder/endpoint`.

The `bundle.pem` has the server.crt and rootCA.crt.

`cat server.crt rootCA.crt >> bundle.pem`

Answer (score 4):

Your error message is :

> unable to get local issuer certificate

That means curl is unable to find the certificate of the issuer (the CA who sign the server certificate) from the trust store :

> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

All you have to do is download the CA certificate and add it to the trust store.