# mTLS without Certificate Authority

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, quarkus

I am trying to implement the scenario **Require the client to identify itself (two-way TLS)** that is described on https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl#require-the-client-to-identify-itself-two-way-tls.

The API server is created with https://quarkus.io/ along with a keystore and a truststore. The keystore contains the certificate plus the private key and the truststore contains the client certificate for the client identification.

Now, I would like to do the request to the API server via `curl` instead java rest client.

I have found, maybe the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920225/1743843 with the command:

```
curl --key client.key --cert client.crt --cacert bundle.pem -X GET -v https://x.x.x.x:xxxx/folder/endpoint
```

the option `--cacert` need to be passed. However, I would like to do **Require the client to identify itself (two-way TLS)** not **Two way TLS based on trusting the Certificate Authority**.
The question is, can I pass anyway on the option `--cert` the server certificate instead CA certificate or there is another option.

I would like to do without self signed certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the `--cert` option, however you need to provide Base64 encoded privatekey pair file. In that tutorial keystore files are used as `jks` which you first need to convert to something what curl will understand and in this case a pem file. What you need to do is:

1. Convert keystore to p12 file
2. Convert p12 file to pem file
3. Run curl command with pem files

#### Convert keystore to p12 file

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore truststore.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore identity.jks -destkeystore identity.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12
```

#### Convert p12 file to pem file

```
openssl pkcs12 -in truststore.p12 -out trusted-certificates.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -out identity.pem
```

#### Run curl command with pem files

```
curl --cert identity.pem --cacert trusted-certificates.pem https://localhost:8443/api/hello
```

These steps can also be found here: [GitHub Gist - Curl with Java KeyStore](https://gist.github.com/Hakky54/049299f0874fd4b870257c6458e0dcbd)